# Seq log ui nuget packages can not loaded

Tags: seq-logging

I would like to use seq log slack web hook configurations but I got this an error. Any idea ? Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using an old Seq version, probably not supporting TLS 1.2.

Updating to the latest Seq version should do the job (though if the OS is pre-Windows Server 2012 R2 you may also need an OS update).